# Cakephp multiple records using foreach

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to insert multiple records using cakephp.My controller code are given below :

```
if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
            foreach($this->request->data['Deal']['deal_date'] as $key => $data)
            {
                $this->Deal->create();
                $this->Deal->id = $id;
                $this->request->data['Deal']['deal_date'] = $data;
                $this->request->data['Deal']['recur'] = $this->request->data['Deal']['recur'][$key];
                if ($this->Deal->save($data)) {
                   $this->Session->setFlash(__('The deal has been saved'));
                   //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The deal could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                }

            }

        }
```

Its not inserting data into database properly.I used array in all the input fields.Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

Use [saveAll or saveMany](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array)

```
if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
    $records = array();
    foreach($this->request->data['Deal']['deal_date'] as $key => $data) {
        $record = $this->request->data;
        $record['Deal']['id'] = $id; // are you sure you need this ?
        $record['Deal']['deal_date'] = $data;
        $record['Deal']['recur'] = $this->request->data['Deal']['recur'][$key];
        $records[] = $record;
    }

    if ($this->Deal->saveMany($records)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The deal has been saved'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The deal could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }

}
```

Comment: Its working but if I put two dates in my input field, it produced counter three i.e its generating three loops.Can you guess ,whats the problem. @cornelb

Answer (score 0):

//try this

```
if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
            $myData = array();
        foreach($this->request->data['Deal']['deal_date'] as $key => $data)
        {
            $this->Deal->create();
            $myData['Deal']['deal_date'] = $data;
            $myData['Deal']['recur'] = $this->request->data['Deal']['recur'][$key];
            if ($this->Deal->save($myData)) {
               $this->Session->setFlash(__('The deal has been saved'));
               //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The deal could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
            unset($myData);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For inserting many rows use savemany or saveall as mention by cornelb,
but try to debug why your code is not working by printing sql log

```
if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
            foreach($this->request->data['Deal']['deal_date'] as $key => $data)
            {
                $this->Deal->create();
                $this->Deal->id = $id;
                $this->request->data['Deal']['deal_date'] = $data;
                $this->request->data['Deal']['recur'] = $this->request->data['Deal']['recur'][$key];
                if ($this->Deal->save($data)) {
                   $log=$this->Deal->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);
                   echo "<pre>";print_r($log);exit;
                   $this->Session->setFlash(__('The deal has been saved'));
                   //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The deal could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                }

            }

        }
```